# Selenium tests sometimes fail, sometimes pass

Tags: asp.net, selenium, nunit

I have created tests using selenium 2, I'm also using the selenium standalone server to run the tests.

The problem is that if I run one test, it works. If I run multiple tests, some of them fail. If I try then to run a failed test, it works.

Could the tests be running on threads? 
I've used the NUnit GUI, and TeamCity to run the tests ... both give the same results : different tests fail, run again, other tests fail.

Any thoughts ?

**EDIT**

The tests shouldn't depend on one another. The database is emptied and repopulated for every test. 
I guess the only problem could be that the database is not emptied correctly ... but then if I run the same test multiple times it should also fail.

**EDIT2**

The tests fail with "element not found".
I'll try and add a "WaitForElement" that retries every few milliseconds and maybe that will fix it.

Comment: what is the nature of the tests?  are they thread safe?  dependent on each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the exact errors that are thrown its hard to say. The normal causes of flakiness tend to be waits are not set to a decent time or the web server can't handle that many requests.

If the DB is on the same machine as the webserver, and why shouldnt it be on a build box, it can be intensive to clear it out.

I would recommend going through each of the errors and making it bullet proof for that and then moving to the next. I know people who run there tests all the time without flakiness so its definitely an environmental thing that can be sorted.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the tests are failing with "Element not found"

Comment: Then your tests are running too quickly for the page that is loading.

Comment: Is there a way to increase that delay globally ? In selenium ?

Comment: Look into implicit wait. A good strategy is to set a decent implicit wait time and then use explicit waits for potentially longer operations.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party here but are you using a single window to run your tests? I had a similar issue since the site I'm testing has only one page load event so waiting for elements or pausing the test became very dodgy and I had different tests passing each time. Adding a ton of wait times didn't work at all until I just opened a new "clean" browser for each test. Testing does get slower but it worked.

Comment: How to do that?